# How can I make random.choices generate more than 1 number?

Tags: python

```
import threading
import time
from colorama import init, Fore
import ctypes
import string
import random

init(convert=True)
ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("Number Generator")

f = open('capodepera.txt', 'a')
print()
print(Fore.RED + 'Enter amount of ips to generate: ')
amount = int(input())
fix = 1
while fix <= amount:
    code = ('').join(random.choices(string.digits.upper())) + "." + ('').join(random.choices(string.digits.upper()))  
    f.write(code.upper() + '\n')
    print(Fore.GREEN + code.upper())
    fix += 1
    ctypes.windll.kernel32.SetConsoleTitleW("generated ips: " + str(fix) + " from " + str(amount))
```

Hi, so I tried to make a IP generator but I don't know how to make random.choices(string.digits.upper())) generate more than 1 number.. I tried everything, but couldn't make it up.

Comment: Did you [read the function documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices) yet? Did you see that there is a `k` parameter, that defaults to `1`? The first sentence of the documentation is "Return a *k* sized list of elements chosen from the *population* with replacement", where the italicised words refer to arguments in the function signature.

Comment: Ooh, right, thanks :)

Comment: I tryed that, but I don't know how to make it generate a random number..

Comment: What does all that code have to do with the question?

Answer (score 2):

Random choice is not the best choice for this.  I would suggest using `random.randrange()` instead:

```
".".join(str(random.randrange(256)) for _ in range(4))

# '150.139.60.176'
```

Comment: Ah, I hadn't quite cottoned on that this is about generating *IP addresses*.

Comment: You may want to add an explanation as to **why** you feel `randrange()` is a better choice here.

Answer (score 1):

You may have missed the [documentation for `random.choices()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.choices), which tells you that there is an argument named `k`:

> `random.choices(population, weights=None, *, cum_weights=None, k=1)`
> Return a *k* sized list of elements chosen from the *population* with replacement.

So `random.choices()` returns a list of size `k`, where `k` defaults to `1`. If you want more than one value in the returned list, set `k` to a different value, e.g. `k=3` to get value values:

```
>>> import random, string
>>> random.choices(string.digits, k=3)
['0', '9', '0']
```

Note that I didn't bother with `.upper()`. Digits don't have upper-case variants, they are not letters.

So, to join two groups of digits with `.` together:

```
''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=3) + '.' + ''.join(random.choices(string.digits, k=3)
```

or use an f-string, and perhaps import just `choices` and `digits`:

```
from random import choices
from string import digits

f"{''.join(choices(digits, k=3)}.{''.join(choices(digits, k=3)}"
```

However, if you are trying to generate an *IP address*, then using `random.choices()` and `string.digits` is *not* the right choice. IP addresses don't normally use `0` digits at the start for example.

Moreover, you are further constrained to numbers between 0 and 256, and certain numbers are reserved (such as private addresses, multicast addresses, the link local and loopback networks and otherwise reserved addresses), you probably don't want to generate *those*!

I'd generate a random 32-bit number (so in `range(2 ** 32)`), feed that number to [`ipaddress.IPv4Address()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Address), then check the `is_global` flag to make sure it is a valid global IP address (ruling out the other cases):

```
from ipaddress import IPv4Address

def random_ipv4():
    """Generate a random but valid global IPv4 address"""
    while True:
        address = IPv4Address(random.randrange(2 ** 32))
        if address.is_global:
            return str(address)   # convert to dot notation
```

This is guaranteed to produce a random but *valid* global IP address every time:

```
>>> print(random_ipv4())
124.34.255.74
>>> print(random_ipv4())
122.124.80.223
>>> print(random_ipv4())
50.242.11.192
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do like this.

```
>>> import random
>>> random.choices(string.digits, k=20)
['4', '1', '5', '9', '7', '6', '4', '0', '4', '7', '6', '1', '9', '9', '4', '8', '5', '0', '1', '6']
```

Comment: `random.sample()` is a *different* function, it picks values without repetition, while `random.choices()` picks values *with* repetition. Note that here you returned 10 values out of 10 possible values, and **nothing repeats**. Now try `random.sample(range(0, 10), 11)`. Then try `random.choices(range(0, 10), k=11)`.

Comment: Why use `randrange()`? `random.choices()` works much better for this task, the OP is already using it.

Comment: Your edit makes your answer the exact same as @MartijnPieters answer.